# How to E2E test data within third party package with Protractor - Angular

Tags: html, angular, testing, protractor, e2e-testing

I am wondering if it is possible to add a unique identifier to a 3rd party package at the root html element level. For example, I am using the package myDatePicker via NPM.

I can add an ID tag to the actual  html element, but nested inside of that element is an  along with two  that I need to add ID's to for E2E testing purposes. We are using protractor for testing.

The inspected html looks like this

```
<my-date-picker ... id="myDatePickerUniqueID" ...>
     <div>
        --><input **'where I want my id field'**>
     </div>
</my-date-picker>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't suggest diving into 3rd party source code as you are then relying on that specific version and that will only cause problems.

What you could do is use `element(by.css('myDatePickerUniqueID div input'))`.

**By.css** -> https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.By.css

Another approach would be to select **By.model** so you are not dependant on HTML/CSS structure, but rather Angular.
Example would be `element(by.model('selectionDayTxt'))`

**By.model** -> https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.model

**All selectors** -> https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy

Comment: Thanks for the help, I think this will work perfectly with the css selector, assuming I can grab the top unique id and drill down from there.